# How make addition of two or more numbers in a single EditText?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have one `EditText` and a `TextView`
and `Button`s to perform addition and number `Button`s, I want the values from the `EditText` and perform operations like add, multiply, divide, etc..., so I just need help with retrieving two values from single `EditText`, my friend suggested me to use `split()`, but I don't have an idea how to implement it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow,
[First of all, check it how to ask a question.] 


 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: First of all develop demo using two editText , then after you will understand next step

Comment: this link will help you >>https://codehandbook.org/simple-android-application/

Comment: why you want to use single edittext ?

Comment: @AD10 Becuase in a mobile calculator there is only one EditText , and it looks good  professional , if i will use two editTexts then it will not look that professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to get text from edittext?

initialize edittext:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
String[] editTextValues = edittext.getText().toString().split(" ");
```

now use editTextValues like this

```
int firstValue =  Integer.parse(editTextValues[0]);
int secondValue = Integer.parse(editTextValues[1]);

int sum = firstValue + secondValue;
```